# Can you make the /vz directory a symlink?

Tags: centos, openvz, virtualization, symlink

I have a OpenVZ VPS server with a 500GB hard drive and 240GB SSD. I'd like to have each VM's files stored on the SSD. Can I make their directory within /vz symlink to a directory on the SSD?

There might be a better way to do this. If you know one, feel free to let me know about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you could just mount the SSD card under `/vz` manually or through your systems `/etc/fstab` file.

First figure out what your SSD card's device handle is (might be something like /dev/sdc1). Then using the mount command:

```
% mount /dev/sdc1 /vz
```

If you're not sure which `/dev/...` is your device, you could use the command `blkid` to help figure it out.